# How to pass angular component to Nebular dialog service

Tags: typescript, dialog, angular6, nebular, ngx-admin

I'm trying to create a web dialog on Agnular6 using `Nebular` components. There are two ways to do this, the first one is to pass `<ng-template>` reference, like:

```js
  openAddDialog = (dialogTemplate: TemplateRef<any>) => {
    this.dialogServiceRef = this.dialogService.open(dialogTemplate);
  }
```

and it's working well. But what I need is to pass a component as a parameter like:

```js
dialogService.open(MyComponent);
```

I have this structure in my app:

```
|_ pages
|   |_ pages.module.ts
|   |_ patient
|      |_ patient.module.ts
|      |_ patient.component.ts
|      |_ patient.component.html
|
|_ shared
    |_ shared.module.ts
    |_ components
    |   |_ search-bar.component.ts
    |   |_ search-bar.component.html
    |
    |_ modal-form
        |_ modal-form.component.ts
        |_ modal-from.component.html
```

I've added the `ModalFormComponent` to the `declarations`, `exports`, and `entryComponents` in the shared module. Also, I imported it in the SearchBar component and run this function on click on a button in searchBar:

```js
openAddDialog = () => {
    this.dialogServiceRef = this.dialogService.open(ModalFormComponent);
  }
```

and I got this error in the browser console:

```
ERROR Error: No component factory found for ModalFormComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
    at noComponentFactoryError (core.js:19453)
    at CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory (core.js:19504)
    at NbPortalOutletDirective.attachComponentPortal (portal.js:506)
    at NbDialogContainerComponent.attachComponentPortal (index.js:17128)
    at NbDialogService.createContent (index.js:17336)
    at NbDialogService.open (index.js:17295)
    at SearchBarComponent.openAddDialog (search-bar.component.ts:46)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (SearchBarComponent.html:11)
    at handleEvent (core.js:34777)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:36395)
```

Any thoughts on what is the problem and how may I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put the component in the entryComponents field in the module (be it main module or a child module, depending on your situation).

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import {
  //...
  NbDialogModule
  //...
} from '@nebular/theme';


@NgModule({
 declarations: [
 //...,
 ModalFormComponent,
 //...
 ],
 entryComponents: [
  //...
  ModalFormComponent,
  //...
 ],
 imports: [
 //...
 // NbDialogModule.forChild() or NbDialogModule.forRoot()
 //...
],
 providers: [
  //...
 ],
})
 export class ExampleModule{
}
```

This should solve your error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You're totally right, that has solved the error!

Answer (score 6):

Use the **context** parameter to pass all the parameters needed.

For exemple, imagine that have this SimpleInputDialogComponent:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NbDialogRef } from '@nebular/theme';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-simple-input-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'simple-input-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['simple-input-dialog.component.scss'],
})
export class SimpleInputDialogComponent {

  title: String;
  myObject: MyObject;

  constructor(protected ref: NbDialogRef<SimpleInputDialogComponent>) {
  }

  cancel() {
    this.ref.close();
  }

  submit(value: String) {
    this.ref.close(value);
  }
}
```

To pass title and myObject, use the context parameter:

```
const sampleObject = new MyObject();
this.dialogService.open(SimpleInputDialogComponent, {
      context: {
        title: 'Enter template name',
        myObject: sampleObject,
      },
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for answering @mabg
But the problem is not how to send components inputs. The problem is that sending component method is not working at all!

Answer (score 1):

This is what `nebular` documents suggest:

```
open() {
 this.dialogService.open(yourComponent, {
   context: {
     title: 'This is a title passed to the dialog component',
   },
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

solution : the params should be obtain on `ngOnInit`, not in constructor